# There is a fork of my organisation's repo on my Github account and I don't know how that happened?

Tags: github

I just started developing for an organisation and cloned their Github repo to my own computer using HTTPS. It's been a few days and I have only been studying the code. Today I noticed that on my own Github account there is a forked version of the organisation's repo. I don't remember forking the project and don't know when or how it happened. It is not impossible that I pressed the fork button on the Github repo page, but I don't think I did. Is there any other way for a repo to get forked to your own account?

When I first cloned the organisation's repo I only had read access to it. I tried to push a new branch to the repo and got an error message (don't remember what it said) and realised that I didn't have write access. Could this have caused the fork to be created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't use the fork button, it's possible you just edited a file from a repository where you don't have write access, in that case it will automatically fork the repo :

[image]

Comment: This is what happened! I had forgotten about it, but I read that this was a good way to check if you have write access, and I used it. Thanks!